# How to fix DTWeakSupport.h file missing in DTCoreText project in IOS?

Tags: ios, dtcoretext

I had referred the following link to use "DTCoreText" inside a project.(https://docs.cocoanetics.com/DTCoreText/docs/Setup%20Guide.html#Framework). I would like to try 2nd option among three options. But i don't know how to use "Something like command prompt lines" like below.

```
libDTCoreText.a (target from the DTCoreText sub-project)
```

Can any one of you please explain "How to link DTCoreText" into a project by giving "Step by step instructions" ?
 Advance thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use DTCoreText with an ios project, i had used Cocoapods. Hope below links will be helpful.

DTCoreText Set Up Guide
https://docs.cocoanetics.com/DTCoreText/docs/Setup%20Guide.html
Cocoapod tutorial for beginners
http://www.raywenderlich.com/64546/introduction-to-cocoapods-2
Cocoapod usage with a sample project
http://www.cocoanetics.com/2013/01/digging-into-cocoapods/

Thanks !